# Generate a rownumber and repeat every five customers in oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

How to generate a row number for every 5 customers in oracle?
For example, if number Of records = 10 the expected output would be: `1..5,1..5`

Like this:

```
CustomerName  Row Number  
A                 1  
B                 2  
C                 3  
D                 4  
E                 5  
F                 1  
G                 2  
H                 3  
I                 4  
J                 5
```

Comment: Does the order of the result set matter? That is, do you need consistency in which name is `1` and which is `5` across repeated executions of the query?

Comment: If you only need it for auto fill in inserts you can use cycle sequence: CREATE SEQUENCE customer_row_number_seq MINVALUE 1 MAXVALUE 5 START WITH 1  INCREMENT BY 1 NOCACHE CYCLE;

Comment: @alexanderanikin - a clever solution but not a really useful one. One, the overhead of creating a database object to solve what can be done in pure SQL. Two, it's not flexible if we need to change the repeating set to say every 6 records.

Answer (score 3):

one solution would be the `NTILE` analytic function: https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/functions127.htm#SQLRF00680

It also deals nicely with cases where the number of customers is not divisible by 5 (e.g. 12 customers).

Sample:

```
with customers as (        
    select level customername from dual connect by level <= 10)
select customername, ntile(5) over (order by customername asc) rownumber
from customers;
```

Comment: For future reference, it's a good idea to reference a current version of the Oracle documentation (unless the OP has indicated they are using a specific version). Oracle 10g has been unsupported and deprecated for years. I know a lot of places are still using it, but my point applies even so.

Comment: @APC thank you. not sure why google so often has the 10g result on top and not a more recent one. and often I forget to check the version then.

Comment: `NTILE` seems to assign 1 to A and B, 2 to C and D, etc.

Comment: I think 10g represents some kind of high watermark for Oracle adoption. So it wouldn't surprise me if there were more blogs, forum posts, etc linking to 10g docs than any other version. Google has gone way beyond relying solely on PageRank but I think it's still an important metric for them.

Comment: @SalmanA yes. but I don't think this is in violation of OP's requirements.

Answer (score 1):

You may use *modular arithmetical* logic as below :

```
select "Customer Name", replace(mod(rn,5),0,5) "Row Number"
  from
(
  select CustomerName as "Customer Name", row_number() over (order by CustomerName) as rn
    from
  (
    select chr(level+64) CustomerName, level as nr
      from dual
     connect by level <= 10 
  )
);
```

[***Rextester Demo***](https://rextester.com/LLC5071)

Answer (score 1):

In Oracle, you can just do:

```
select t.*, 1 + mod(rownum - 1, 5) as rownumber
from t;
```

You can replace `rownum` with `row_number() over (order by . . . )` as well.

Answer (score 0):

this also works (oracle); alter this according to your needs

select

'data' data_column,

rownum original_rownum,

replace(mod(rownum,5),0,5) expected_rownum

from

your_table;

Answer (score 0):

My solution uses ROW_NUMBER to assign a value to each row and then applies the MOD function to split it into 5's.
Whilst this works I think the other solution using NTILE is cleaner.

```
WITH cust AS
  (SELECT customername, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY customer_name) AS ordering
   FROM customers)
SELECT customername , CASE WHEN MOD(ordering,5) = 0 THEN 5 ELSE MOD(ordering,5) END AS bucket
  FROM cust;
```

Comment: Ah... just subtract 1 before mod, add 1 after mod.

Answer (score 0):

this will do:

```
select e.*, mod(rownum-1,5)+1 rownumber
from (select * from table_name) e;
```